# How do I code a sigmoid function for a neuron in a neural network in swift?

Tags: swift

I am making my own neural network directly in Xcode playground and I have most of it, but for calculating the value of each neuron, in the end I need to use a sigmoid to make it a value between -1 and 1. I'm not sure about the math itself, so I have no idea how to do this programmatically.
Here is the code I currently have. Mainly just look at the neuron function and I have a comment in there indicating where I would have it. Ty so much to anyone in advanced (:
Code:

```
import Cocoa

var inputs: [Double] = [0, 0, 0, 0]//*

//2 neuron hidden layer

var outputs: [Double] = [0, 0]//*
//Inputs and outputs of the neural network
//*not for training

func neuron1_1 (_ Weights: [Double] = [0, 0, 0, 0], _ bias: Double) -> Double {

var myProduct: Double = 0
myProduct = myProduct + inputs[0] * Weights[0]
myProduct = myProduct + inputs[1] * Weights[1]
myProduct = myProduct + inputs[2] * Weights[2]
myProduct = myProduct + inputs[3] * Weights[3]
//multiply all weights with inputs
myProduct = myProduct + bias
//add the output
//Sigmoid function here
return myProduct

}

func neuron1_2 (_ Weights: [Double] = [0, 0, 0, 0], _ bias: Double) -> Double {

var myProduct: Double = 0
myProduct = myProduct + inputs[0] * Weights[0]
myProduct = myProduct + inputs[1] * Weights[1]
myProduct = myProduct + inputs[2] * Weights[2]
myProduct = myProduct + inputs[3] * Weights[3]
//multiply all weights with inputs
myProduct = myProduct + bias
//add the output
//Sigmoid function here
return myProduct

}

func neuron2_1 (_ Weights: [Double] = [0, 0, 0, 0], _ bias: Double) -> Double {

var myProduct: Double = 0

myProduct = myProduct + neuron1_1([0, 0, 0, 0], 0) * Weights[0]
myProduct = myProduct + neuron1_2([0, 0, 0, 0], 0) * Weights[0]
myProduct = myProduct + bias

return myProduct

}

func neuron2_2 (_ Weights: [Double] = [0, 0, 0, 0], _ bias: Double) -> Double {

var myProduct: Double = 0

myProduct = myProduct + neuron1_1([0, 0, 0, 0], 0) * Weights[0]
myProduct = myProduct + neuron1_2([0, 0, 0, 0], 0) * Weights[0]
myProduct = myProduct + bias

return myProduct

}


func cost () -> Double {

var cost: Double = 0
//                                              ˘ use for training. Represents the desired 
output
cost = cost + pow((neuron2_1([0, 0, 0, 0], 0) - 0 ), 2)
cost = cost + pow((neuron2_2([0, 0, 0, 0], 0) - 0 ), 2)

return cost

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sigmoid function is simply

```
func sigmoid(z: Double) -> Double {
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-z))
}
```

This returns either 0 or 1 except for the short transition section, which you can make arbitrarily small.

I strongly suggest that you learn linear algebra. That'll save you a world of pain.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/working_with_matrices